# Does any country apply universal jurisdiction to coups d'état?

Tags: international, extraterritorial-jurisdiction

Several countries apply [universal jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_jurisdiction) when suspects are prosecuted for major crimes such as genocide, war crimes, ethnic cleansing and crimes against humanity. Among other examples, this allowed for [Anwar Raslan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anwar_Raslan) to be convicted of crimes against humanity in Germany, for crimes committed while he was in Syria.  Considering some of the answers to *[At what point is it "legal" to overthrow the government?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/89019/3569)* which essentially state that if you succeed in overthrowing the government, nobody will prosecute you for it, I wonder:

Is there any country applying universal jurisdiction allowing for prosecuting a coup d'état happening in another country?

Wikipedia doesn't seem to list any, but Wikipedia may be incomplete.

Comment: Maybe this fits better on [Politics.SE] — I'm not sure.  Universal jurisdiction does have political issues.

Answer (score 2):

### Sort of

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

A coup d'état would, almost certainly, involve acts or planning for acts captured by Australia’s laws against [terrorism](https://www.ag.gov.au/national-security/australias-counter-terrorism-laws).

> A terrorist act is an act, or a threat to act, that meets both these criteria:
>
> - it intends to coerce or influence the public or **any government** by intimidation to advance a political, religious or ideological cause.
> - it causes one or more of the following:
>
> .   - death, serious harm or danger to a person
> serious damage to property
>
> .   - a serious risk to the health or safety of the public
>
> .   - serious interference with, disruption to, or destruction of critical infrastructure such as a telecommunications or electricity network.

As drafted, the laws require no connection to Australia.

Comment: This answer shows that Australia persecutes acts of terrorism against other governments within their own jurisdiction, but does Australia also claim jurisdictions for acts of terrorism that were performed outside of Australia? If someone would assassinate the president of Arstotzka while visiting Canberra, this Australian anti-terrorism law would certainly apply, because it happened in Australia. But would it also apply if the same thing happened in Kolechia?

Comment: I did some research and found that [in 1991, the Australian High Court confirmed universal jurisdiction for *war crimes*](http://www8.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/cases/cth/HCA/1991/32.html), but a coup d'état is not necessarily a warcrime.